# How do you "win" Sleeping Beauty?

Tags: sleeping-beauty

At the bottom of the game's homepage, you can see a "Fun Fact" that says

> This game can be won!

When I get to the top of the tower, it says

> Welcome to the last floor!
>
> You finally managed to reach the princess and finish the game.

But, I haven't kissed any princesses yet (one of the only actions you have, besides attacking monsters or interacting with heroes).

The princess is surrounded by impassable pillars and unmovable and unattackable heroes.

```
T@T
@P@
T@T
```

The heroes only ever say

> You can do whatever you want here, but beware - no kissing!
>
> We only have one rule here: no kissing!
>
> Make sure you don't wake her up!
>
> Sssh! She is sleeping, don't you see?
>
> I see, another lucky adventurer!

Is there a win condition besides simply reaching the top of the tower and loafing with all these other heroes?

Comment: I removed that "seven day roguelike" tag after doing some research. In the future, please don't add meta tags like that. A single game tag is sufficient for like 95% of the questions asked.